# Ошибка при запуске приложения Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-jdbc

Пытаюсь создать CRUD-приложение с использованием Spring Boot и PostgreSQL. При запуске выдаёт следующие ошибки:

```
Error creating bean with name 'employeeDaoImpl' defined in file [D:\Projects\simplewebapp\target\classes\com\way\dao\impl\EmployeeDaoImpl.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'dataSource' or 'jdbcTemplate' is required

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'dataSource' or 'jdbcTemplate' is required
```

**AppConfiguration.java :**

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.way.task")
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class AppConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    Environment environment;

    private final String URL = "url";
    private final String USER = "postgres";
    //private final String DRIVER = "driver";
    private final String PASSWORD = "50easY?";

    @Bean
    DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource driverManagerDataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        driverManagerDataSource.setUrl(environment.getProperty(URL));
        driverManagerDataSource.setUsername(environment.getProperty(USER));
        driverManagerDataSource.setPassword(environment.getProperty(PASSWORD));
        //driverManagerDataSource.setDriverClassName(environment.getProperty(DRIVER));
        return driverManagerDataSource;
    }
}
```

**application.properties :**

```
server.servlet.context-path=/simplewebapp

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/employeesdb
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=password

spring.datasource.platform=postgresql
```

**EmployeeDaoImpl.java :**

```
public class EmployeeDaoImpl extends JdbcDaoSupport implements EmployeeDao {

    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;



    @Override
    public List<Employee> getAllEmployees() {
        return jdbcTemplate.query("SELECT * FROM employees", (rs, rowNum) -> {
            Employee employee = new Employee();
            employee.setEmployeeId(rs.getLong("employee_id"));
            employee.setFirstName(rs.getString("first_name"));
            employee.setLastName(rs.getString("last_name"));
            employee.setDepartmentId(rs.getLong("department_id"));
            employee.setJobTitle(rs.getString("job_title"));
            /*employee.setGender(rs.get("gender"));
            employee.setDateOfBirth(rs.getDate("date_of_birth"));*/
            return employee;
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void addEmployee(Employee employee) {
        jdbcTemplate.update("INSERT INTO employees(employee_id, first_name, last_name, department_id, job_title/*, gender, date_of_birth*/) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?/*, ?, ?*/)",
                employee.getEmployeeId(), employee.getFirstName(), employee.getLastName(),
                employee.getDepartmentId(), employee.getJobTitle()/*, employee.getGender(), employee.setDateOfBirth()*/);
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteEmployee(Long employeeId) {
        jdbcTemplate.update("DELETE FROM employees WHERE employee_id = ?", employeeId);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateEmployee(Employee employee) {
        jdbcTemplate.update("UPDATE employees SET first_name = ?, last_name = ?, department_id = ?, job_title = ?/*, gender = ?, date_of_birth = ?*/ WHERE employee_id = ?",
                employee.getFirstName(), employee.getLastName(), employee.getDepartmentId(),
                employee.getJobTitle()/*, employee.getGender(), employee.setDateOfBirth()*/);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решено добавлением в EmployeeDaoImpl.java следующего кода:

```
@Autowired
private DataSource dataSource;

@PostConstruct
private void initialize() {
    setDataSource(dataSource);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Проверьте правильность этих строчек

```
private final String DRIVER = "driver";
driverManagerDataSource.setDriverClassName(environment.getProperty(DRIVER)); 
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
```

Вы пытаетесь вытянуть проперти с названием `DRIVER` а такой проперти у вас нет

Comment: не знаю насколько это глупое решение,но удалив эти строки, кол-во ошибок уменьшилось - остались только ошибки в которых требует `'dataSource' or 'jdbcTemplate'`